# GRASS and SAGA CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

Tags: python, saga, linux

I have a problem. I am developing a standalone app using QGIS but my script imports GRASS nad SAGA plugins and I have error to create the maps.

I have CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core). SAGA is not recognized.

Can you explain what I have to do?